# PPO, A2C for continuous action spaces, math and code

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Edit:
Question has been edited to better reflect what I learned after asking the original question.

I implemented the clipped objective PPO-clip as explained here: https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/ppo.html

Basically I used a dummy actor network to find the new action probability without training the local actor network.

```
"""use temp_actor to get new prob so we don't update the actual actor until
        we do the clip op"""
        curr_weights = self.actor.get_weights()
        self.temp_actor.set_weights(curr_weights)
        self.temp_actor.fit(state, advantages, epochs=1, verbose=0)
        new_policy = self.temp_actor.predict(state, batch_size=1).flatten()
        new_aprob = new_policy[action]
```

Then I worked out the ratio of action probabilities and implemented the PPO clipping parts of the algorithm:

```
ratio = new_aprob / old_aprob
        # scale = min(ratio * advantages, K.clip(ratio, 1 - self.epsilon, 1 + self.epsilon) * advantages)
        no_clip = ratio * advantages
        clipped = np.clip(ratio, 1 - self.epsilon, 1 + self.epsilon) * advantages

        self.actor.fit(state, np.minimum(no_clip, clipped), epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

The full code is here (please excuse some coarse language in the comments):    https://github.com/nyck33/openai_my_implements/blob/master/cartpole/my_ppo_cartpole.py

How can I adapt it for a continuous action space problem such as Pendulum v0.
Update:  I just read that the distribution of actions is a normal or Gaussian distribution here:  [Reddit normal distribution](https://www.reddit.com/r/reinforcementlearning/comments/adg447/ppo_with_continuous_actions/)

That seems strange since I imagined the curve of actions to be skewed one way or another depending on whether a particular state would get better results with certain action tendencies.

Update:  I found this on the Stable baselines site for PPO:

[image: return probability distribution]

From this URI:  [ppo explanation](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo2.html)

I also saw that section 13.7 in Sutton's RL book seems to be a must-read for this type of problem as the section is titled:  Policy parameterization for Continuous Actions.

Furthermore I also learned in the process of searching for a readable implementation that GAE (advantage) is normalized so that probably makes an implementation more robust against wild fluctuations.  I also think my implementation is incomplete, ie. missing other components compared to the Pytorch "solution" I linked to in the answer.

Comment: Your question is not about code review by itself but about learning, you can remove that from your title and the last phrase as well since that is a second question (and a meta question) inside the question.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte, sounds good!  Had no idea what a meta question was until now but it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packt Publishing's "Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-On" has an entire chapter on continuous action spaces.  Here is the math in the book:

[image: math for continuous action space]

and the code accompanying the book:  [code repo for book](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On)

The code for the math above is in:

> The complete source code is in Chapter14/02_train_a2c.py ,
>   Chapter14/lib/model.py and Chapter14/lib/common.py . Most of the code
>   will already be familiar to you, so the following includes only the
>   parts that differ. Let's start with the model class defined in
>   Chapter14/lib/model.py .